# Enlarging the logo on modern experience viewlsts page

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page, site-logo

I am looking to enlarge the logo or at least replace the current logo square box with a larger rectangle image in SharePoint's modern experience. Adding a rectangular logo automatically compresses the logo in the square box, making it illegible. 
[image]

[image]